# Binding Z-scores into a dataframe in R using a single function

Tags: r, normalization

Presently, I am trying to create a `function` that will calculate the `z-score` of given variable `y` in a dataset `x` and create a new `column` appended to the dataset. Ideally, I would like to automatically name the new `Z column` with the variable involved (e.g. for input `y` named `ppm`, the new `column` would be `ppm_Z`). The current code returns the Z list, but does not append it to the dataframe. The 'getSD' function is my own - just something to switch between population and sample SD with the default being sample.

```
 getZ <- function(x, y){
     i <- 1
     Z <- c()
     while(i <= length(y)){
         Zscore <-(y[i] - mean(y))/getSD(y)
         Z <- c(Z,Zscore)
         i <- i + 1}
     return(Z)
    x$Z_score <- Z
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `base::scale` function effectively implements Z-score, and tools like `dplyr` provide ways to operate on multiple columns and append transformed results.

```r
library(dplyr)

head(iris)
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

dplyr::mutate_at(iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length"), list(Z=scale))
##     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Sepal.Length_Z Petal.Length_Z
## 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa    -0.89767388    -1.33575163
## 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa    -1.13920048    -1.33575163
## 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa    -1.38072709    -1.39239929
## 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa    -1.50149039    -1.27910398
## 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa    -1.01843718    -1.33575163
## 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa    -0.53538397    -1.16580868
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code can give you some hints

```
> x <- data.frame(y1 = 1:5, y2 = 2:6)

> cbind(x, setNames(Map(scale, x), paste0(names(x), "_Z")))
  y1 y2       y1_Z       y2_Z
1  1  2 -1.2649111 -1.2649111
2  2  3 -0.6324555 -0.6324555
3  3  4  0.0000000  0.0000000
4  4  5  0.6324555  0.6324555
5  5  6  1.2649111  1.2649111
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dplyr and the 'across' function to apply a user generated function across all numeric cols to calculate z_scores, and use the .names parameter in across to create newly named columns. Something like this:

```
get_z_score <- function(x) (x-mean(x)) / sd(x)

iris.zscores <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), get_z_score, .names = "{col}_zscore"))

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length_zscore Sepal.Width_zscore Petal.Length_zscore Petal.Width_zscore
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>                 <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>              <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa               0.267              0.190               -0.357             -0.436
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa              -0.301             -1.13                -0.357             -0.436
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa              -0.868             -0.601               -0.933             -0.436
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa              -1.15              -0.865                0.219             -0.436
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa              -0.0170             0.454               -0.357             -0.436
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa               1.12               1.25                 1.37               1.46 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa              -1.15              -0.0739              -0.357              0.512
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa              -0.0170            -0.0739               0.219             -0.436
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa              -1.72              -1.39                -0.357             -0.436
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa              -0.301             -0.865                0.219             -1.39
```